# Java Adding Image to BLOB datafield

Tags: java, derby, embedded-database

For this university assignment that I have been assigned.

I have to develop an application for use on a PDA which is running J2ME and Apache Derby in embedded mode.

I would like to both import/export an image to the database. How would I do this? Also would storing the image as a blob be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve and upload your images from the database you will need the Derby JDBC driver.  Read the [Derby wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/) for more info.

[Blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) stands for binary large object, and would be good to store an image in.

[JDBC tutoiral](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Using Derby on Java ME platforms [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/JavaMESupport).

Good Luck.